# How to subset a dataframe with a conditional statement based on multiple column values

Tags: r, subset, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to subset a dataframe  on the basis of conditions from multiple columns. Here is my dataframe.

```r
var1 <- c(x,x,x,y,y,z,z,z,z) 
var2 <- c(a,b,c,a,b,a,b,c,d) 
var3 <- c(2,4,1,4,1,6,2,5,8)
data1 <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     var1 var2 var3
# 1    x    a    2
# 2    x    b    4
# 3    x    c    1
# 4    y    a    4
# 5    y    b    1
# 6    z    a    6
# 7    z    b    2
# 8    z    c    5
# 9    z    d    8
```

## Output

The output I expect is:

```r
#     var1
# 1    y
# 2    z
```

## Condition

The following are the conditions leading to the output:

> 1. The output is a dataframe where only values of `var1` are selected.
> 2. Values of `var3` where `var2` is equal to `a` is greater than values of `var3` where `var2` is equal to `b`.

I'm unable to create a code based on this complicated condition from multiple columns.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the expected output, and your attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This can give you a factor:

```r
subset(data1, (var2=="a"))[subset(data1, (var2=="a"))$var3 > subset(data1, (var2=="b"))$var3, "var1"]

# [1] y z
# Levels: x y z
```

You can use `data.frame` to get what you want as follows:

```r
data.frame(var1 = subset(data1, (var2=="a"))[subset(data1, (var2=="a"))$var3 > subset(data1, (var2=="b"))$var3, "var1"])
#   var1
# 1    y
# 2    z
```

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive solution might be to use a for-loop. Probably, there are shorter and more elegant ways to solve this problem, but this should work:

```
selection <- c()

for(i in unique(var1)) {
  var_store <- data1 %>%
    filter(var1 == i, var2 == a | var2 == b)

  if(filter(var_store, var2 == a) %>% 
    select(var3) %>% 
    as.numeric() > 
  filter(var_store, var2 == b) %>% 
    select(var3) %>% 
    as.numeric()) {

    selection <- c(selection , unique(var_store$var1))
  }
}

data1 %>% 
  filter(var1 %in% selection)


# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   var1  var2   var3
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 y     a         4
# 2 y     b         1
# 3 z     a         6
# 4 z     b         2
# 5 z     c         5
# 6 z     d         8
```

Comment: I have been able to get the desired answer by transposing the dataframe using dcast()

Comment: @sayandesarkar, in that case, you can answer your own question and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that reshaping the dataframe can solve my problem. I have been transposed var2  using dcast() to get the desired result